# Where can I find the SQL to get the most used information by wordpress database?

Tags: query, sql

I tried to google "`wordpress sql to get post url`" and I was pretty astonished I couldn't find any resource sharing the **`SQL code`** to join the `wp_post` table with the table containing the **permalink**.

How would you face this 'challenge'?

Is there any resource sharing this kind of information?

Comment: Why do you need SQL? Can you not use the WordPress PHP function `get_permalink()`? Besides, the permalink is not stored in the database, it's generated on the fly based on the post slug and site URL settings (never, *never* rely on `guid` in the posts table)

Comment: How does wp resolve every single visit which is asking to visualize page xxx/yyy.htm without storing the permalink somewhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I  tried to google "wordpress sql to get post url" and I was pretty
>   astonished I couldn't find any resource sharing the SQL code to join
>   the wp_post table with the table containing the permalink.

That is because there is no table containing the permalink. Your "challenge" and your "astonishment" are because you've imagined the system to work in a way that it doesn't. The permalink isn't stored anywhere. It is calculated based on the permalink settings in the backend. If you want to see how that happens, take a look at the source code for [`get_permalink()`](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.4/src/wp-includes/link-template.php#L117). The only thing saved to the database is the permalink pattern, which is saved to the options table under the `permalink_structure` key and looks something like:

```
/%year%/%monthnum%/%day%/%postname%/
```

But, of course, that varies for the numerous different structures possible.

Comment: How does wp resolve every single visit which is asking to visualize page xxx/yyy.htm without storing the permalink somewhere?

Comment: Sorry. I just explained that. The permalink structure is saved and the PHP works out the rest.

Comment: Thanks, maybe now I got how it works.. the postname is stored on db and I hope it's an indexed field. When the user asks for page with postname = XXX, wordpress probably makes a query for postname = XXX.